# Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'. styles.xml Android AAPT

Tags: android

I am getting error as

```
Type error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.    styles.xml  /res/values line 7  Android AAPT Problem
```

I have created the android app using settings in Android JUNO: 
Min Req SDK: API 8, 
Target SDK: API 21, 
Compile With: API 25, 
Theme: Holo Light with Dark Action Bar (Also tried with None), 
Create Activity: checked, 
Create Activity: Blank Activity (Also tried Empty Activity),

I have also tried upgrading Android Support Library from Android sdk, but did not help.
When I tried to import, AppCompat is not present anywhere. 
Also when I tried to Add Library from Project Properties, there is no AppCompat available there.

Please help me with detailed explanation or let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read because you mix quotations and your text without any differentiation. Please improve the text with the tools right above the edit window. Further tips: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Which OS are you running your IDE on?

Comment: OS is windows 10

Comment: anyone has an answer on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this one by downloading [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html) and while installing I have selected "Do not import anything from previous installation". There may be problem with my previous installation with Eclipse Juno. 
I Hope this will help someone looking for an answer.